# Is there an easy way for sed to 'h' if hold space is empty and 'H' if not empty?

Tags: sed

For example, to move lines containing `foo` to before other lines --

```
$ printf '%s\n' bar1 foo1 foo2 bar2
bar1
foo1
foo2
bar2
$ printf '%s\n' bar1 foo1 foo2 bar2 | sed -n '/foo/!H; /foo/p; ${x;p;}'
foo1
foo2

bar1
bar2
```

Here the first `H` command generates a blank line before the first `foo`.

For now as a workaround I manually removed the leading `\n` with `${x;s/^\n//;p;}` --

```
$ printf '%s\n' bar1 foo1 foo2 bar2 | sed -n '/foo/!H; /foo/p; ${x;s/^\n//;p;}'
foo1
foo2
bar1
bar2
```

Comment: @anubhava i want to move `foo` lines to in front of other lines. (print lines containing `foo` first, before printing other lines.)

Answer (score 4):

> Is there an easy way for sed to 'h' if hold space is empty and 'H' if not empty

No. You could:

```
x; /^$/!{     # if hold space is not empty
   x;H;       # do H
bEND; }; {    # if hold space is empty (ie. branch to end if not empty)
   x;h;       # do h
}; :END;
```

In a script it would look like:

```
printf '%s\n' bar1 foo1 foo2 bar2 | sed -n '/foo/!{x;/^$/!{x;H;bEND};x;h;:END}; /foo/p; ${x;p}'
```

But TBH there's an easier way - just remove the newline from the output...

```
${x;s/^\n//;p;}
```

Comment: based on yours, a bit shorter one: `sed -n '/foo/!{x;/./{x;H;bq};x;h;:q}; /foo/p; ${x;p}'` :)

Comment: What if the file contains empty lines or all the lines contain `foo`?

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/foo/p;//!H;$!d;x;s/.//p;d' file
```

If a line contains `foo` print it otherwise append it to the hold space.

If it is not the last line, delete it otherwise, swap the to the hold space, remove the first character and print the result.

N.B. The non `foo` lines will only be printed if they have been appended in the first place. The printing is dependent on the removal of the introduced newline via the substitution command flag `p`. If the hold space is empty the `d` command will prevent the implicit printing. Thus the `H` command provides a way of determining if the hold space has been used.

Comment: learned a few things from you: `//!`, `s///p`, and the shorter `s/.//`.

Comment: and this works with both GNU sed and BSD (macos) sed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to consider `awk` then it is pretty simple:

```
printf '%s\n' bar1 foo1 foo2 bar2 |
awk '!/foo/{a[++n]=$0; next} 1; END{for (i=1; i<=n; ++i) print a[i]}'
```

```
foo1
foo2
bar1
bar2
```

Comment: yes i understand awk is much easier here. just want to find out if sed can do the trick easily. :)

Comment: Seeing n sed answer, it surely doesn't look easy to me :)

Answer (score 0):

In case you are ok with `awk`, could you please try following.

```
printf '%s\n' bar1 foo1 foo2 bar2 | 
awk '
/^foo/{
  print
  next
}
!/^foo/{
  val=(val?val ORS:"")$0
}
END{
  print val
}'
```

***Brief explanation:*** Going through all lines of `printf`'s output, which is sent as standard input to `awk`. Then printing lines which are starting from `foo` else keep adding its value to variable `val`. In `END` block of `awk` which will be executed after all Input is done with reading, printing the variable `val` there.